# Importing JSON file with python

Tags: python, json, api

I have imported a json file with python and still read the first json elements
i need to add a loop for to read all the file

JSON file content

```
 [
        {
            "severity": 4,
            "status": "OPEN",
            "id": 1987,
            "description": "Multiple Login Failures for the Same User containing Bad Username",
            "start_time": 1525269490400
        },
        {
            "severity": 4,
            "status": "OPEN",
            "id": 1986,
            "description": "Multiple Login Failures for the Same User containing Bad Username",
            "start_time": 1525269181679
        },
.
.
.
.
.
    ]
```

and this is the python script

```
# Prepare the sample Alert

with open('output.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data,) 
if severity=data[0]['severity'] < 4:
    severity=1
elif severity=data[0]['severity'] > 6:
    severity=3
else:
    severity=2  
alert = Alert(title=data[0]['description'],
              date=data[0]['start_time'],
              severity=severity,
              description='N/A',
              type='Offense',
              source='QradarSiem',
              sourceRef=data[0]['id'])
```

i know that i need to use

```
for line in f:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

but i don't know where and how to use it, can you help ?

Comment: `if severity=data[0]['severity'] < 4`  is not valid Python.

Comment: in English, "boucle" is spelled "loop".

Comment: Please rephrase. Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? What is a 'boucle'?

Answer (score 1):

> i know that i need to use `for line in f:       data.append(json.loads(line))"`

Why on earth would you do that ??? You've already parsed the whole file, you have a list object back, all you have to do is iterate on the list.

```
with open('output.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data,) 

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the line

```
 data = json.load(json_data,)
```

you already have all the data loaded. Now you can just iterate over 'data':

```
for item in data:
    if item['severity'] == 4:
        do_something(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import json
with open("infile.json","r") as infile:
    val = infile.read()
    json=json.loads(val)
print(json)
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Just providing code is not often enough to provide full context to support your answer.